# DJANGO | Redirect/Disable URLs based on environment variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

Usecase: I have some features that I don't want to release as of yet so I want to disable certain URLs or redirect them to 404/505s in production environment.

Is there a way to accomplish that using just the environment settings instead of popping out routes in urls/urlpatterns.

Answer (score 1):

You could read the environment variable from `os.environ` and if it is a certain value (or just present in this example) append your paths that enable the feature(s)

```
import os

from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('foo/', views.foo),
]

if os.environ.get('ENABLE_FEATURE'):
    urlpatterns.append(path('bar/', views.bar))
```

Comment: Can this be easily tested by patching the ENABLE_FEATURE in a test case?